# Save mysql query results to HTML file in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, save

I want to save 20-30 MySQL query results to .html files separately.

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT....")
while ($t = mysqli_fetch_assocc($query)) {
    // The other queries and html content** <- I want to save these.
}
```

So I want to save the result, not the source code, I think it should execute and then a script save it to html, because in the future I want to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
or 
[fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)